# Triple Sum construction

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, solution-verification

I have the following:
$$a_3b_0c_0+a_3b_1c_0+a_3b_0c_1+a_4b_0c_0+a_3b_2c_0+a_3b_1c_1+a_3b_0c_2+a_4b_1c_0+a_4b_0c_1+a_5b_0c_0$$
I can rearrange then to get
$$a_3b_0c_0+$$
$$a_4b_0c_0+a_3(b_0c_1+b_1c_0)+$$
$$a_5b_0c_0+a_4(b_0c_1+b_1c_0)+a_3(b_0c_2+b_1c_1+b_2c_0)$$
Then
$$a_3\sum_{j=0}^0b_jc_{0-j}+$$
$$a_4\sum_{j=0}^0b_jc_{0-j}+a_3\sum_{j=0}^1b_jc_{1-j}+$$
$$a_5\sum_{j=0}^0b_jc_{0-j}+a_4\sum_{j=0}^1b_jc_{1-j}+a_3\sum_{j=0}^2b_jc_{2-j}$$
I think the next step then is
$$\sum_{k=0}^0\sum_{j=0}^ka_{3-k}b_jc_{k-j}+\sum_{k=0}^1\sum_{j=0}^ka_{3+1-k}b_jc_{k-j}+\sum_{k=0}^2\sum_{j=0}^ka_{3+2-k}b_jc_{k-j}$$
Finally, combining gives me...
$$\sum_{m=0}^2\sum_{k=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^ka_{3+m-k}b_jc_{k-j}$$
Can any one tell me if this is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.

You can verify by running through the indices and calculating the values on the subscripts.  The limits on your indices result in the correct number of terms, and there is an exact match with the calculated subscripts in the expanded sum.

```
m   k   j   3-m-k   j   k-j
---------------------------
0   0   0     3     0    0
1   0   0     4     0    0
1   1   0     3     0    1
1   1   1     3     1    0
2   0   0     5     0    0
2   1   0     4     0    1
2   1   1     4     1    0
2   2   0     3     0    2
2   2   1     3     1    1
2   2   2     3     2    0
```

Comment: Great.  Thank you for the help.